# window.location does not works the same way in IE9 and FF

Tags: javascript

```
function showBookings(transactionID) {
    window.location = "txgateway/bookingsSearch.do?ctrl=tabsetTransactionSearch&action=TabClick&param=bookings&transactionId=" + transactionID;
}
```

in FF is:

```
http://localhost/name/txgateway/bookingsSearch.do?ctrl=tabsetTransactionSearch&action=TabClick&param=bookings&transactionId=1
```

and in IE

```
http://localhost/name/txgateway/txgateway/bookingsSearch.do?ctrl=tabsetTransactionSearch&action=TabClick&param=bookings&transactionId=1
```

i am calling it from:

```
http://localhost/name/txgateway/transactionDetails.do?transactionId=1
```

what to do that lionk will be the same in FF and IE. The right one is in FF.

Comment: Um, the right one is IE. unless my morning coffee has not kicked in and I am not reading the path right. You should not have the directory if you are in that current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the `txgateway` from the relative path since `transactionDetails.do` and `bookingsSearch.do` are in the same directory:

```
window.location = "bookingsSearch.do?...";
```

Or use an absolute path starting at the root:

```
window.location = "/name/txgateway/bookingsSearch.do?...";
```

Otherwise, with `txgateway` already a directory in the current `window.location`, it should appear twice in the resulting URL when it's mentioned again in the relative path.

So, IE is correct in this case. While Firefox apparently recognized the repeat of `txgateway` and tried to correct it.